# Java Kryo - backward compatibility issues and strict serialization / deserialization process

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, backwards-compatibility, kryo

We use Kryo to serialize big java objects when passing them in a HTTP request between multiple clients and one common server.

Lets say for example, we serialize an object like this:

```
class Person {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }
}
```

now, we have two main issues that cause a lot of headache and extra coding:

1. when we need to change the `Person` object (add new field for example) - in order to keep backward compatibility with old clients who still use the **old `Person` object** - we create another `Person` class (`v2.Person`).

   Then we deserialize data from old clients using the old `Person`, and from the new clients using `v2.Person`. This creates a lot of code duplication.
2. If, for example, I move the `v2.Person` object to another package, it causes issues like the following:

   say I moved the class from `old_pacakge.v2.Person` to `new_package.v2.Person`. When I try to deserialize the `v2.Person` object coming from the client - I get `ClassNotFoundException: old_pacakge.v2.Person`.

   *To clarify - The client uses the `Person` object from a dependency jar created by the server code.*

   I know that this is because on **serialization**, kryo writes the class name, and on **deserialization**, it tries to find that class in the classpath and fails (because `v2.Person` moved).

   Ideally - I would like to be able to serialize a class with a certain structure - and deserialize it with another class which has the same structure **but is not dependent on the class location**.

We weren't able to solve those two issues. We've been reading a lot on Kryo and how people handle backward compatibility issues, but found that a lot of people have the same problems and couldn't find easy / standard solutions.

Are there standard / best practices to solve those problems?

Comment: Just curious, why not to use JSON (or any other similar format) to pass structures around? Converting JSON to a class can easily be done using Jackson, Gson, or any other library.

Comment: You are correct that JSON will be much easier to serialize / deserialize, but its also a much bigger object. With kryo, the serialized string is much smaller.